# How to set alarm between two dates in Android?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set alarm between two dates.
For example `date1 = 02/12/2105` and `date2 = 21/12/2015`
alarm should fire every day between date1 and date2
I have tried using below code

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);    
}
```

Comment: But you need to specify a hour right? maybe 12:00 of every day between those dates?

Comment: and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: yes alarm should fire on specific time on every day between two dates